# Flagging "You're missing...." answers

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, not-an-answer

After this [incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225352/flags-reviewing-link-only-answer-dilemma), I became more careful whenever I flag or review flags.

I have flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604976/1771795) which should be a comment instead, even if it solves the problem and the question itself should be closed as well, if the problem was a typos.

[image]

I am dead sure that SO doesn't encourage such answers, because they have no added value. In my humble opinion, answers should be comprehensive and clear to reflect professionalism.

I am just surprised that my flag was *declined*, yet the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604976/1771795) was deleted and converted into a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604881/ajax-request-in-jquery-mobile/22604976#comment34483534_22604881).

[image]

**Edit:** comment = not an answer

[image]

- Are such answers encouraged on SO?

  - You are missing an "apostrophe"
  - You are missing a "hash tag"
  - Your code works on "fiddle"
- Does SO (users/mods) consider such answers as real *answers*?
- Is an answer...?

  - That solves current question/concern?
  - That solves current question/concern and others in the future?

My question is, was I mistaken for flagging this answer? Would I be mistaken for flagging such answers in the future?

Comment: The problem is with the question, not the answer.  You also cannot expect an SO user with 16 rep to be able to vote to close the question.  It just turned out to be a silly mistake when the OP typed the question so converting to a comment was quite appropriate.

Comment: @UphillLuge The answer doesn't solve the problem either. Pls check OP's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604881/ajax-request-in-jquery-mobile/22604976#comment34483535_22604881). Converting it to a comment means my flag was correct, wasn't?

Comment: It did, he fixed his question.

Comment: @UphillLuge the poster has 16 rep so he can't comment. A comment isn't an answer, thus should be deleted and converted into a comment, so the flag is correct.

Comment: I don't care how terse the answer is, or how silly the question is, If it is a solution to the problem that the OP posted about than it definitely **is** an answer.

Comment: @downvoter late one, where were you 17 hours ago?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used a "Not an Answer" flag.  You run the risk of getting your flag declined if you use that flag on answers that look like answers.

Not an Answer flags are for things like:

- +1, would read again
- Did you order this pizza?
- @SomeOtherUser I think...

Cast a custom moderator flag instead, and put in the custom flag description an actual explanation: "This doesn't answer the question asked; it should be a comment instead."

**Rule of thumb:** If you have to look at any other part of the post (the question, other answers, other comments) to evaluate whether or not an answer is an answer, don't use the "Not an Answer" flag on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880820/codesmith-ntier-layer-connectionstring/21881761#21881761) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222394/using-object-prototype-tostring-call-to-return-object-type-with-javascript-n/4222434#4222434) which were _disputed_?

Comment: Yes, like those two.  Those are answers.

Comment: As per your answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22600755/1771795) will be declined then.

Comment: Yep, that's an answer too.

Comment: Btw, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880820/codesmith-ntier-layer-connectionstring/21881761#21881761) was flagged with "other" and I have explained that it is not even related to the OP. I'm not arguing, just wondering why it was disputed.

Comment: @Omar: That one had eight flags (most of which were "Not an Answer" flags), and mods don't have the ability to decline or approve them individually.  It only takes one disagree flag for them all to be disputed.

Comment: I have 509 helpful, 113 disputed and 30 (+1 maybe) declined. How bad is my situation? and how can I correct it?

Comment: Sounds like you're still in the ballpark.

Comment: "ballpark" means so so. Good to know! and thanks again for clarifying this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I declined that, and I should probably provide a little more context for why I did and then converted that to a comment.

First, it was an attempt at answering the question by pointing out that there was a potential problem in the code they'd posted. Since answers with "not an answer" flags that are marked helpful, then deleted, are [used as audit cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently), I wanted to prevent this from being used as one. This answer would very easily trip up reviewers as an audit case, since it was a legitimate attempt to fix something in the question.

I then decided to convert it to a comment, because it was helpful that they pointed out the typo, but the asker then corrected this part of the question. The question had changed to make that no longer relevant as an answer, but the answer did provide some history for why the question code had been changed. I thought it could help explain this change best as a comment.

I hope that makes a little more sense now.

Comment: If I had used "others" instead of "not an answer", would my flag be declined too?

Comment: @Omar - If you'd flagged it as "This answer addresses a typo that was fixed in the current version of the question, is no longer relevant, and should be converted to a comment", sure, I would have gladly accepted that. However, this was a particular case, and not every short answer that attempts to fix something in the question deserves to be removed or converted to a comment.

Comment: Thank you, the vision is clear now. However, I still find such answers inadequate and have no real value within. But since they are accepted on SO, then I have to live with it.

Comment: @Omar: I think what Brad really said (in a nutshell) is that you need to *communicate.*  Use moderator flags to explain what the problem is, and what you want us to do about it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm communicating now; I'm trying hard to help. I'm in _love_ with [tag:jquery-mobile] as I dedicate a lot of time and effort. Maybe I'm pushing it too far or am being rather dramatic.

Comment: Declined flags is part of the process.  If you never get a declined flag, you're not flagging hard enough.

Comment: Well said @RobertHarvey this is what I wanted to hear.

Comment: @Omar tell me again what you thin is inadequate about answers like that.  I don't think I understand.  If a question can be solved by correcting a single typo, than an answer like that is not only appropriate, but it's **optimal**

Comment: @SamIam You have your opinion and I have mine, there is no need to argue. "_With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming._" and "_We're a little bit different from other sites._" [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/about).